# Test tableless model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

When I run 'rake test' I get this error:

1) Error:
test_the_truth(DetailsThankYouTest):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: details: DELETE FROM "details" WHERE 1=1

The application runs fine but I cannot write any simple test. How can I disable Rails test to use the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add a fixture file for this model by accident?

According to the [testing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html):

> Rails by default automatically loads all fixtures from the test/fixtures folder for your unit and functional test. Loading involves (...) removing any existing data from the table corresponding to the fixture.

Comment: Yes the test_helper.rb does that

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have a class which doesn't have a table itself but which has subclasses which do. In which case you can set:

```
class Details < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```